# Determining position of rotated object

Tags: c++, opengl, math, 3d

I'm writing a project in OpenGL and I've encountered a problem with determining the position of object after translating and rotating the Model-View Matrix.
Just to visualize this, imagine how Earth is rotating around Sun, basically, I need to determine postion of Earth at runtime.

I'll divide my code into a few steps, let's assume we are at starting position of (0,0,0) and our rotation is equal to 0.

```
while(true)
{
modelViewMatrix.PushMatrix();              // 
    modelViewMatrix.Translate(1, 1, 0);    // 1
    modelViewMatrix.Rotate(k++, 0, 1, 0);  // 2
    object.Draw();                         // 3
modelViewMatrix.PopMatrix();               //
}
```

1 - At this point determining position is easy, it's (1, 1, 0)
2 - Now we are rotating object over some constantly incrementing value to keep it moving around position (0, 0, 0)
3 - Drawing the object

Now I know that modelViewMatrix stores information like rotation and position but I don't know how to utilize this to find out the actual position of my object after translating and rotating it.

Here's my try at drawing what I'm talking about, the red question mark (?) indicates an example position  of object that I'm trying to find.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to create Vec3 at (0,0,0) and transform it by your matrix.  That will give you the position of your 'Earth' - Your object probably already has a position, so you really should be using your matrix to transform your object's actual position rather than changing your entire model-view matrix just to draw the object there.

If you're curious how these matrices work, google "homogeneous transformation matrix" to read up on them.

Comment: Ahh the solution was so close! I once had a thought like "Cant I just multiply  m*v and that would be position" but I dropped this idea, now it turns out to be the solution! Thanks mate! : )

Comment: Glad it worked.  Definitely read up on those matrices - it's really good to understand what they are.